# How can I store the displayValue inside a for loop and makeuse of that value in global scope?

Tags: javascript, dom

How can I store the display value in a variable which I can then access in the global scope - (store and access the value inside the for loop):

```
let a, b;
numbers.forEach(function(number){
    number.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        a = displayValue.textContent += this.value; //I want to store this value

    });

})
console.log(a) //this will return undefined since the a in global scope hasn't been affected
```

[image]

So in this image 567 is the displayValue I would want to store so I can make use of it later.
Just a little context, `numbers` is a nodeList of buttons with numbers attached to it - I used a for loop to iterate and attach eventlisteners to each of these buttons - which has led me to my current situation of trying to store the displayValue inside a global variable for use later.

Comment: 1. You may use `var` declaration to ensure `a` is global.
2. Your `a` variable will be assigned only after you click the button.

Comment: I've already made use of ```let``` outside in the global scope - doesn't that still make ```a``` global - and if I wanted to assign the display value to ```a``` shouldn't it be done inside the eventListener after click has happened since that's what I want the calculator to do

Answer (score 0):

it returns undefined because is set later - you already set the global `a` in addEventListener

but the click event hasn't been emitted yet

so you already store it properly

also you can use `window.a` (both to set and get), but no need here

Comment: what do you mean by it being set later? It's declared before the iteration, and is stored inside the eventListener so how can I then make use of that value outside the loop scope because ```a``` is still set to undefined?

Comment: outside `a` will be set then click emits. by addEventListener you only create a function, not run it, so `a` still remains undefined. when it runs, `a` will be the set value. Maybe you need some action after setting `a` inside addEventListener, not after creating the function and not running it